# How do I test a sequelize database updating function like this?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, sequelize.js

Hi I can I test a function like this? I cannot test it properly because it says that relation "facilities" does not exist, however I now it exists because I can add a new record.
I should I test this code:

```
export async function postMemberController(req, res) {
  try {
    if (req.decodedToken.user_id || req.decodedToken.id) {  
      const facility = await db.facility.findOne({
        where: { id: req.body.facility_id },
        raw: true,
      });

      if (!facility?.id) {
        res.send(
          "no facilities"
        );
      } else {
       
        let member = await db.member.findOne({
          where: { id_no: Number(req.body.id_no) },
          raw: true,
        });
 
        const admin = await db.user.findOne({
          where: { facility_id: req.body.facility_id },
          raw: true,
        });
        const data = await db.sequelize.transaction(async t => {
          if (member?.id_no) {
            await db.member
              .update(
                {
                  ...req.body,
                  facility_id: [...new Set([...member.facility_id, req.body.facility_id])],
                },
                { where: { id_no: member.id_no } },
                { transaction: t }
              )
              .catch(e => console.log('error : creation MEMBER??? ', e));

            const adminToken = await tokenCreator({ ...admin }, 3);
            !req.body?.from &&
              (await axios
                .put(
                  `${process.env.CENTRAL_URL}/members`,
                  {
                    body: {
                      ...req.body,
                      facility_id: [...new Set([...member.facility_id, req.body.facility_id])],
                      from: 'web',
                    },
                    where: { id: member.id },
                  },
                  {
                    headers: { authorization: 'Bearer ' + adminToken },
                  }
                )
                .catch(e => console.log('erorr ', e.response.data, e.config.url)));
          } else {
            const auth = adminFirebase.auth;

            const firebaseToken = await auth.createCustomToken(generateUUID());

            member = await db.member
              .create(
                {
                  ...req.body,
                  firebase_token: firebaseToken,
                  facility_id: [req.body.facility_id],
                  creator: admin.user_id,
                  updater: admin.user_id,
                },
                { transaction: t }
              )
              .catch(e => console.log('error : creation MEMBER??? ', e)); 
            if (member) {
              const card = await db.card.findOne({
                where: { card_id: member.dataValues.card_id },
                raw: true,
              }); 
              if (card) {
                await db.card.update(
                  { card_number: req.body.card_number },
                  {
                    where: {
                      card_id: member.dataValues ? member.dataValues.card_id : member.card_id,
                    },
                  },
                  { transaction: t }
                );
              } else {
                const newCard = await db.card.create(
                  {
                    card_number: req.body?.card_number,
                    card_id: member?.dataValues?.card_id,
                    creator: admin.user_id,
                    updater: admin.user_id,
                    facility_id: req.body.facility_id,
                    credits: 0,
                  },
                  { transaction: t }
                ); 
              }
            }

            const adminToken = await tokenCreator({ ...admin }, 3);
            !req.body?.from &&
              (await axios
                .post(
                  `${process.env.CENTRAL_URL}/members`,
                  {
                    ...req.body,
                    id: member.dataValues.id,
                    card_id: member.dataValues ? member.dataValues.card_id : member.card_id,
                    facility_id: req.body.facility_id,
                    from: 'web',
                  },
                  {
                    headers: { authorization: 'Bearer ' + adminToken },
                  }
                )
                .catch(e => console.log('erorr ', e, e?.response?.data, e.config.url)));

            !req.body?.from &&
              (await axios
                .put(
                  `${process.env.CENTRAL_URL}/cards`,
                  {
                    body: {
                      card_number: req.body.card_number.toString(),
                      facility_id: req.body.facility_id,
                      from: 'web',
                    },
                    where: {
                      card_id: member.dataValues ? member.dataValues.card_id : member.card_id,
                    },
                  },
                  {
                    headers: { authorization: 'Bearer ' + adminToken },
                  }
                )
                .catch(e => console.log('erorr ', e.response.data, e.config.url)));
          }

          return member; 
        });
        delete data.dataValues?.password;
        delete data?.password;

        const memberToken = await tokenCreator({ ...data.dataValues }, 3); 
        return res
          .status(200)
          .json({ data, session_id: data.id_no || data.dataValues.id_no, token: memberToken });
      }
    } else {
      return res.sendStatus(401);
    }
  } catch (error) { 
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
}
```

this is how I try to test it:

```
  it('post member from web terminal', async () => {
    try {
      jest.mock('../db/models/index.js', () => {
        const SequelizeMock = require('sequelize-mock');
        const dbMock = new SequelizeMock();
        const facility = dbMock.define('facilities', {
          id: '6-30189',
        })
        const member = dbMock.define('members', {});
        const card = dbMock.card('cards', {});
      });
      const req = {
        decodedToken: { user_id: makeId() },
        body: member,
      };

      const res = {
        sendStatus(num) {},
        status(num) {
          return { json(payload) {}, send(payload) {} };
        },
      };

      const request = await postMemberController(req, res);
      delete member.from;
      expect(request).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ ...member });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('ERROR post member ', error);
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  });
```

How do I write a test for this???? when I call postMemberController inside jest it seems that can't find the relations in the table, I tried to console.log db.facility object from jest test output, there is nothing, not even empty object or null or undefined. I don't understand why? How can I solve this??

Here is the object  I am sending:

```
 const card_number = 11111111111111;
  const card_id = makeId();
  const schedule = makeId();
  const club = makeId();
  const trainer = makeId();
  const user = makeId();
  const facility_id = '6-30189';

  const member = {
    from: 'central',
    card_number: card_number,
    id: makeId(),
    first_name: 'Demo',
    last_name: 'Demo',
    id_no: card_number,
    card_id,
    home_phone: null,
    urgent_phone: null,
    email: null,
    registered: true,
    schedule,
    club,
    trainer,
    birthplace: 'Gölbaşı/Ankara',
    birthdate: new Date().toISOString(),
    father_name: null,
    mother_name: null,
    gender: null,
    profession: null,
    address: null,
    phone_number: null,
    hes_code: null,
    blood_type: null,
    nationality: null,
    profile_photo: null,
    is_employee: false,
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    updatedAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    firebase_token: null,
    file: null,
    session_ids: null,
    facility_id,
    following: null,
    creator: user,
    updater: user,
  };
```

Comment: when running test with jest, run it with flag ```--silent=false```

Comment: @NizarZizoune I still get the same error

Comment: that is for the logging.

Comment: ok, thank you, but still nothing new

Comment: In your controller, you are expecting to find ```req.body.facility_id``` I don't see you passing it anywhere in your ```req``` object.

Comment: I declared the object before the it function and I didn't copy it, I 'll do in a minute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250284/discussion-between-nizar-zizoune-and-fafa).

Comment: https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/nodejs-testing-routes-and-controllers.